# Elasticsearch matching a date with slash characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I need users to be able to find people with a certain date of birth as well as being able to search on just the birth year. The date of birth is currently stored as a string in format "dd/MM/yyyy". The reason I didn't use a date field was because of the need to match on year only, and also the text the user inputs is searched is across a number of fields including name etc, so a string search is necessary. However a search with slashes doesn't work - searching "18/09/1998" does not match a person with that DOB, for example. Do I need to keep a separate `not_analyzed` version of the field to achieve that?

Comment: could you also share mappings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your field is assigned to a `custom analyzer` which prevents the query to return any matches.

One solution is to keep another subfield of `date` with the `keyword` type.

It allows you to search for `18/09/1998` as an exact match.

Try to use this query:

```
  GET my_index/_search
  {
    "query": {
      "term": {
        "date.keyword": {
          "value": "18/09/1998"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Base on mappings:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you need to update your mapping (with the `keyword`) you will have to reindex your documents in order to apply the change.

**Update mappings**

```
POST my_index/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "date": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update index documents**

To achieve that you can use [_update_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html)

```
POST my_index/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
```

Hope this helps